# Generate WSDL request/response without stub

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, wsdl

I would like to create a dynamic web service caller in C++ which you can give it a WSDL URL and the data. The program will generate the request, insert the data, then send the request and get the response then return it to the client.

My question resides in using the WSDL URL to generate an XML request from it (e.g. return an empty XML template that I have to fill like SOAP UI).

Is there any reliable, ready made API that could handle this matter in C++ or do I have to code it myself?

I checked out "gSOAP", but it generates stub methods which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check wsdlpull http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/ that try to do what you describe.

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly what I want.